# autohotkey if statement with and without curly braces

Tags: autohotkey

I don't understand the difference between Autohotkey's `If` and `If(...)`
According to everything I have found, `If(...)` behaves as "expected" but there is something not working with my code.

Below *does not* work. It seems the statement in the `If` is never evaluated, `%TimeString%` is never set and nothing is output:

```
CapsLock & T::
    Input Key, L1
    If (Key=T)
    {
        FormatTime, TimeString,, HHmm
    }
    Send %TimeString%
```

Below *does* work, `%TimeString%` is set and the time is output.

```
CapsLock & T::
    Input Key, L1
    If Key=T
        FormatTime, TimeString,, HHmm
    Send %TimeString%
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autohotkey has two different syntaxes: [legacy](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#legacy-syntax) and [expression](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#expressions). This also affects the [if statement](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Language.htm#if-statement).

When you use parenthesis, [if (expression)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) is used and `Key` is compared to the ***variable*** `T` which doesn't exist and is the same as an empty variable which doesn't equal <kbd>T</kbd>. You need to changed it to `If (Key="T")` and then it will compare the variable `Key` to the String `"T"` and it will work.

In the second case you're using the traditional(legacy) [If](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfEqual.htm) which compares the variable `Key` to the String `T` and because they are equal, it works.

The curly braces `{` `}` just define a block, they do nothing and change nothing when your block contains only one line.

Comment: There is [v2](https://www.autohotkey.com/v2/). It's in perpetual alpha but usable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this code is identical to your script? Beause

```
Tjs := T
if (Tjs=T)
{
   MsgBox true
}
```

works fine for me.